# MySQL NOFILE limits on WSL2

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am running MySQL on WSL2 for Windows. At WSL2 startup, MySQL does not start and I get the following error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I then run this command to get it going:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

And get the following output:

```
 * Starting MySQL database server mysqld
 su: warning: cannot change directory to /nonexistent: No such file or directory
[ OK ]
```

When I check my MySQL error logs, I see this error regarding max_open_files and table_open_cache:

```
2022-07-28T08:36:34.074107Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010139] [Server] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 8161)
2022-07-28T08:36:34.074111Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010142] [Server] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 4000)
```

My understanding is I need to edit my **/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service** file to change this, but when I check that file I see that *LimitNOFILE* is already set to 10000

```
# MySQL systemd service file

[Unit]
Description=MySQL Community Server
After=network.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=notify
User=mysql
Group=mysql
PIDFile=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld
TimeoutSec=infinity
Restart=on-failure
RuntimeDirectory=mysqld
RuntimeDirectoryMode=755
LimitNOFILE=10000

# Set enviroment variable MYSQLD_PARENT_PID. This is required for restart.
Environment=MYSQLD_PARENT_PID=1
```

It's almost as if that setting get's ignored at service startup? Does anyone know where the right place is to set it if this isn't?

Comment: Please ask database admin related questions at their dedicated DBA sister-site of SO, not here on the programming focused SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check information in `/etc/security/limits.conf`
You can add something like (assuming you run `mysqld` as `mysql` user)

```
mysql           hard    nofile     10000
mysql           soft    nofile      8192
```

and in `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
open_files_limit = 10000
table_open_cache=4096
```

then logout, login and restart `mysql`